# Unable to install package "Phytotools"

Tags: r

Does anyone know what version of R "phytotools" is made for? I have the most recent version of R, (I updated it today, 2022-08-17), and i need to download phytotools. However I get an error message and cannot figure out what version of R it needs. Thanks

```
   install.packages("phytotools")

   Warning in install.packages :
   package ‘phytotools’ is not available for this version of R

   A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
   see the ideas at
   https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: @Robert, seems like it exists https://rdrr.io/cran/phytotools/man/

Comment: looking at the rdocumentation for phytotools it was last updated in 2015. What version of R(Studio) are you using?

Comment: @Omniswitcher  I downloaded R version 3.1.3 (2015) and 3.1.2 (2014) and tried to download it on both and it still seems to say it is not available for this version

Comment: I managed to manual install the package as a phytotools_1.0.tar.gz file!